# C++: Confusion on auto deduction using a const against an array

Tags: c++, c++11

Example code:

```
int aa[] = {1,2,3,4};
auto const p = aa;
```

Why `p` deduced as `int *const` instead `int const *`?

Comment: Because `auto const` always gets deduced to a `const`-something. `auto` means "something". `const auto`, therefore, means "const something". `const int *` is not a `const`-something, it's a pointer to something that's `const`. Big difference.

Comment: You can see similar behaviour in `using T = int *; const T var;`, which makes `int *const` instead of `const int *`.

Comment: Am I missing something? What is `arr`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth probably the opposite of missing something. You've noticed a typo, that no-one else did.

Comment: As C-arrays are not copyable, `aa` would decay to pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Because `aa` is a non-const array, it will decay to pointer-to-non-const and therefore `p` will be deduced to be a pointer-to-non-const. And because you declared `p` const, it will be a const pointer-to-non-const.

Declaring a variable const will make that variable const. It doesn't make the type of the variable different (pointer-to-const and pointer-to-non-const are different types) except in the sense that it may be a const qualified version of that same type.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is little more than that, when You wrote:

```
auto const p = aa;
```

it means:

```
auto const p = &aa[0];
```

so on the right hand side we have pointer to int (not const pointer to int!), so following auto type deduction rules it evaluates to template like this:

```
template<typename T>
void func_for_ptr(const T* param);
```

So in our case parameterType is `const T*`
but T itself is pointer to int. 
Constness of type is not changed!

The same effect can be observed other way around, try to define template:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T param) {
    int tmp = 0;
    T val = &tmp;
    *val = 0;
}

int main() {

 int *x = new int(1);
 foo(x);
}
```

T was not deduced to  pointer to const so You r able to override ptr, but if You will write:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T param) {
    int tmp = 0;
    T val = &tmp;
    *val = 0;
}

int main() {

 const int *x = new int(1);
 foo(x);
}
```

Type T will be deduced to pointer to const and you will get error. In shortcut auto is always like parameter type.